# Faster way to retrieve the files size from a ITEMIDLIST (pidl)

Tags: c++, windows, shell, explorer

I saw a bunch of samples to show an explorer like view. Like this one from PJ Naughter http://www.naughter.com/shellctrls2.html

The problem is always the speed.

The bottleneck is the evaluation of the file size. Here is is done with an extra call to get the file status (last change date and file size).

```
case static_cast<int>(Columns::SizeColumn): //deliberate fallthrough
case static_cast<int>(Columns::DateModifiedColumn):
{
  CString sPath;
  CFileStatus fs;
  if (pItem->m_pidlFQ.ToPath(sPath) && CFile::GetStatus(sPath, fs))
  {
    CString sText;
    if (nColumn == static_cast<int>(Columns::SizeColumn))
    {
      if ((fs.m_attribute & (CFile::directory | CFile::volume)) == 0)
        OnFormatFileSize(fs.m_size, sText);
    }
    else
      OnFormatFileDate(fs.m_mtime, sText);
    return sText;
  }
  break;
}
```

But this is slow. Isn't there an easier way, to get the modification date and the file size directly from the pidl?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the size and date is cached in the pidl 99% of the time and you don't have to ask the filesystem. You must never convert the pidl to a path, instead use the shell API.

If you only care about Vista and later you can use `SHCreateItemFromIDList`+`IShellItem2::GetUInt64 (PKEY_Size, &size)`, otherwise you have to use `SHBindToParent`+`IShellFolder2::GetDetailsEx`.